# Where do prose rhythms come from?

Tags: style, rhythm

Do you think that the rhythms of poetic prose compositions are produced by their author with a sense of rhythm in mind, or by tinkering with their wording until they arrive at a rhythm they like?

I am asking because after wanting to emulate the prose rhythm of the KJV Bible for several years, when I was about 21 years old I wrote a five paragraph piece with perfect prose rhythm, whose rhythm was not an imitation of anything I ever read before. And I wonder how the rhythms of the first poetic prose compositions were formed.

I am talking about any kind of prose in a style above the plain style, such as the Bible, certain kinds of speeches, certain kinds of fictional works, etc.

Where do prose rhythms actually come from? Are they learned by imitation and discovery? Or are they formed by the imagination with little effort?

This question may seem off-topic, but it is actually a practical question of how to write with rhythm.

Comment: "Do you think that the rhythms of poetic prose compositions are produced by their author with a sense of rhythm in mind, or by tinkering with their wording until they arrive at a rhythm they like?" Both. And it doesn't seem off-topic so much as it seems like a duplicate of most of your other questions. You are not going to get a satisfactory answer here to 'how do I write good?'. People have tried, but you keep coming back with essentially the same question. Read. Write. Rewrite. I don't know what more we can give you.

Comment: A semi-inconnu poet by the name of Edgar Allan Poe wrote an essay on the matter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Poetic_Principle